# Header Check C# is always 403?

Tags: c#, http, header, ping

im trying to ping a list of domains to get initial indications if they exist - if they dont exist i dont get a ping back - which throws and exception. not a problem, except for some reason redirects also dont ping back.

so im trying to get the http header responce of the exception url. but no matter what i get a 403 response. any ideas?

```
private void hunt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string hostAddress = txtKeyword.Text;
        string combined;

        string[] strArray = new string[] { ".com", ".net", ".org", ".ca", ".gov" };

        foreach (string str in strArray)
        {

            combined = hostAddress + str;


            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                int timeout = 1500;
                PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(combined, timeout);


                if (pingreply != null && pingreply.Status.ToString() != "TimedOut")
                {
                    result = "Address: " + pingreply.Address + "\r"
                         + "Roundtrip Time: " + pingreply.RoundtripTime + "\r"
                         + "TTL (Time To Live): " + pingreply.Options.Ttl + "\r"
                         + "Buffer Size: " + pingreply.Buffer.Length + "\r";

                    listBox1.Items.Add(combined + " " + result);
                }
                else
                {

                    listBox1.Items.Add(combined + " not found");
                }

            }


            catch (Exception pingError)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www."+combined);
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
                listBox1.Items.Add(status);
            }

        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

EDIT Ping error as follows:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping     request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout,     Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout,     Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout)
   at DomainHunter.Form1.hunt_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
```

Comment: Ping will be unreliable for this purpose, since many firewalls will be blocking ping requests. If you just want to check if a domain exists, you'd probably be better off using (e.g.) [`Dns.GetHostAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx).

Comment: Does pingError.Message or pingError.StackTrace give you any helpful info?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646755/c-net-find-out-whether-a-server-exists-query-dns-for-svc-records

Comment: Ping error added above if it helps :-)

Comment: @ScottStevens - The error you posted only says that the host didn't respond to your ping. Isn't this the reason for your try catch in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic appears to be backwards (as I read it anyway). If the ping throws an exception if it *doesn't* get a response then sending a `HEAD` request to the server is usually hopeless since the server probably doesn't exist.

Beyond that ping is not really a good option for what you're trying to accomplish. You could do a combination between a `Dns.GetHostAddresses` (as was suggested in the comments) and just try to open a TCP connection to port 80 and/or 443 (which ever is appropriate for the sites you're trying to check) with the `TCPClient` class to determine if there actually is a server listening on the IP discovered. There is little else that will actually verify that there is actually a server listening on the IP you're trying to check. It doesn't check if the URL is valid though so maybe a `HEAD` after proving the server is there would be a good addition.